# CoreData: Trying to sort

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities : `EntityA` and (<-->>) `EntityB`

and I am trying to fetch all `EntityA` sorted by `EntityB.displayOrder`

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<EntityA> = EntityA.fetchRequest()
  context.perform {

    do{
        var data = try self.context.fetch(request)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true)

        for (index,dat) in data.enumerated() {
          let entitiesB = (dat.entitiesB?.sortedArray(using: [sort]))
          data[index].entitiesB! = NSSet(array: entitiesB!)
        }

        self.testListTableVC.testData2 = data
        self.testListTableVC.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

sort seems to be working, but when setting it back to `data` it isn't sorted..

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting `entitiesB`, and then setting the `data[index].entitiesB` equal to `entitiesB` casted as an `NSSet`. If you read about `NSSet`s in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsset), you'll see that they are not sorted lists.

You're essentially doing superfluous work, because you're sorting this array and then casting it as an unsorted `NSSet`

I don't know how you have your model setup, but it looks like you need this `data` for your `testListTableVC.testData2` property. And it seems like whatever kind of array `data` is, it has a property called `entitiesB` which is an `NSSet`. I would recommend making it so that you can use a Swift Array, which would stay organized.

Comment: What if I would use Arrangement : Ordered for the relationship? By parsing all the data to a swift array seems like more work than using data from database straight away. Or could it be sorted on the request itself?